# Path functions available to Jelly script?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, jelly

I'd like to be able to do things like separate the *directory* and *file* name from a full path in Hudson/Jenkins's jelly script.

For example if I have `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.ext` I'd like to (in jelly script) get access to `/dir1/dir2/dir3` and `file.ext`.

Are the java io functions like getPath() and getName() available to jelly script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dion Gillard's [Jelly: Executable XML](http://www.slideshare.net/diongillard/gillard2-jelly) deck was really helpful in sorting this out. From the slides I learned about the [invoke](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/tags.html#core%3ainvoke) (and [invokeStatic](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/tags.html#core%3ainvokeStatic)) tags which were exactly what I needed. The [Apache FilenameUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) has some very nice static methods for dealing with filenames and it's included with Hudson.

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core">
  <j:set var="fullpath" value="/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.ext"/>

  <!-- get the path without the filename -->
  <j:invokeStatic var="justpath" method="getPath" className="org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils">
    <j:arg value="${fullpath}"/>
  </j:invokeStatic>

  <!-- get just the filename -->
  <j:invokeStatic var="justname" method="getName" className="org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils">
    <j:arg value="${fullpath}"/>
  </j:invokeStatic>
</j:jelly>
```

In the example above, *justpath* will be set to `/dir1/dir2/dir3/` and *justname* will be set to `file.ext`.

Comment: This helps me when handling the regex in Jenkins plugin dev.